# ssrs report email subcription is working only for the domain Admin

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, reporting

I am running SQL Server 2016 and if i loin as Administrator i can create email subscriptions. When one of the other users logs in and create an email subscription I he gets the following error.

> Failure sending mail: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details.Mail will not be resent.

The user trying to create the subscription is the ssrs security settings is set to be System Administrator, System User.

Here is the error in ReportServerService__08_22_2023_00_02_32.log file

> library!ReportServer_0-1!4390!08/22/2023-00:02:32:: i INFO: Call to GetPermissionsAction(/REPORT1/OTP). User: ACC\LIUT.
> library!ReportServer_0-1!4390!08/22/2023-00:02:32:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.WindowsAuthz5ApiException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.WindowsAuthz5ApiException: Windows returned a ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED error when Reporting Services attempted to call the Windows Authz APIs. If this issue persists the Reporting Services account may not possess permission to perform authentication checks. Check the Windows Authz documentation for more information and details on diagnosing issues. Authz method: AuthzInitializeContextFromSid, Error code: 5, UserName: ACC\LIUT.;

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Added the user to the SQL server local admins.
Made user that the user inside SSRS security section is set to System Administrator, System User.

I was expecting to see that the user can create email subscription.

Comment: *"If this issue persists the Reporting Services account may not possess permission to perform authentication checks."* Have you checked that?

Comment: Where should i check ?

Comment: Is the report accessing file shares? Have you gone to Reporting Services Configuration Manager > Subscription Settings and confirmed which account is configured for use by SSRS Subscriptions to access file shares? Does that account actually have the required access to the file shares used by the report?

Comment: The report is not accessing any file shares, these are all done on the server from web browser.